# Pushing to GitHub Container Registry: unauthorized: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided

Tags: github, github-container-registry

When I try:

```
docker push ghcr.io/username/imagename:latest
```

as per [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry), I see

```
unauthorised: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
```

How do I push the image to ghcr?

Answer (score 8):

You have to give docker permission to push to your GHCR (instructions are in the github docs, but are somewhat buried).

3 Steps:

1. Create an access token (PAT) ([here](https://github.com/settings/tokens)) and give it **read/write packages** permissions.
2. Copy the PAT to clipboard, and run this in your terminal:

```
docker login ghcr.io -u username -p ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

replacing `username` with your GitHub username, and `ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` with the PAT you just made. Now docker has access to your GHCR, including the ability to push.

3. Try your `push` command again and it will work:

```
docker push ghcr.io/username/imagename:latest
```